# How to await multiple tasks, that were created inside await foreach?

Tags: c#, async-await, entity-framework-core

When using `AsAsyncEnumerable` and `await foreach`, each item is lazy loaded. Per item I want to call a method `DoSomething`, that returns `Task`. The method calls should happen in parallel. When all tasks complete, the below method should return `Unit`.

```
public async Task<Unit> Handle(SomeRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var entities = _dbContext.MyModel
        .Where(...)
        .AsAsyncEnumerable();

    await foreach (var item in entities)
    {
        _ = item.DoSomething();
    }

    return Unit.Value;
}
```

I am not sure how to await all tasks when using `await foreach`. Would this be the right approach?:

```
public async Task<Unit> Handle(SomeRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var entities = _dbContext.MyModel
        .Where(...)
        .AsAsyncEnumerable();

    List<Task> tasks = new();

    await foreach (var item in entities)
    {
        tasks.Add(item.DoSomething());
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    return Unit.Value;
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using the new (.NET 6) [`Parallel.ForEachAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreachasync) API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The given example should work, especially if you expect fairly few items.

Since you have no (visible) mechanism to limit the number of concurrent tasks you might suffer problems if you have a lots of items. You might for example exhaust the threadpool. If the amount of work done per item is very small it might also benefit from processing batches of items. To handle cases like these you might consider using something like [DataFlow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library), it should allow you to specify the degree of parallelism.

Comment: Thx! I will look into DataFlow. The number of items per execution is in the hundreds most of the time, rarely thousands. The amount of work per item is small.